# js log binded object

Tags: javascript, bind

I have a function binded to an object, how can I access to the object at the same scope with the function?

```js
let f = function(){};
class A{}
f = f.bind(new A());
// console.log(f.bindedObject)
```

---

what about in a method?

```js
class B{
    constructor(func){
        this.func = func;
    }

    log(){
        // console.log(this.func.bindedObject)
    }
}

class A{}
let b = new B(function(){}.bind(new A()));
b.log()
```

Comment: Using `this` keyword?

Comment: Can’t you just use `this`?

Comment: By the way I think you can't rebind an arrow function!

Comment: that was not I implied, sorry I will edit the question

Comment: question updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could overwrite the `bind` method

```js
(function() {
    let bind = Function.prototype.bind;
    Function.prototype.bind = function(newThis) {
        let bf = bind.apply(this, arguments);
        bf.newThis = newThis;
        return bf;
    };
})();

var f = function() {};
var nf = f.bind({'hello':1});
console.log('newThis', nf.newThis);
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the suggestion, add the binded object as a property would be a great solution. However, I wonder if there is a generic built-in property for it.

Comment: As far as I know, there's no such a built-in way